# Giving different parts of an input value

Tags: python

I have a task to rearrange a name to last first middle initial. I know for this I can use split() but I'm trying to understand it the way I'm learning it right now which is index and find ect to rearrange it. My question is how would I make it so the program knows what is the first last and middle names since it changes depending on user input. I've tried this and it doesn't work. Is there a way to do this?

```
Name = input("Enter a name like 'First I. Last: ")
words = Name.find(" ")
first, middle, last = words[1], words[0], words[-1]
```

Comment: By Last First Middle initial do you mean that Some Random Name would turn into NRS?

Comment: Shouldn't you `split` the name by space rather than using `find`? `Name.split(" ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find will return the index into a string of that occurence, you can then use that index to slice your original string, find also takes an optional second index to tell it where to start searching from ...

```
Name = input("Enter a name like 'First I. Last: ")
first_space_index = Name.find(" ")
first_name = Name[:first_space_index]
# find the first space that comes after first_space_index
second_space_index = Name.find(" ",first_space_index + 1)
middle_initial = Name[first_space_index+1:second_space_index]
```

this is not nearly as good of a solution as just using split but meh ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `string.split()` function to gather the different words in the input. This is preferable to using `string.find()` as you do not have to slice to find the answer.

```py
name = input("Enter a name like 'First I. Last: ")
words = name.split()
first, middle, last = name[0], name[1], name[2]
```

Then you can work out the first letter of each `'Hello'[0] -> 'H'`